# Joining 3 Tables into 1 - 1 table is aggr table

Tags: sql, join, left-join

Good Day,

I have 3 seperate tables.  2 header tables (1 row of information each) and 1 transaction table (numerous rows).

I want to join the aggregated table onto the header tables.  The below are my 3 tables which i need to join.  Please can someone assist with the syntax.

```
ARTRNDETAIL:
SELECT 
    SalesOrder
    TrnYear,
    TrnMonth,
    InvoiceDate,
    StockCode,
    QtyInvoiced
FROM ArTrnDetail 

SORMASTER:
SELECT 
    SalesOrder,
    OrderDate,
    ReqShipDate
FROM SorMaster

SorDetail:
SELECT SalesOrder,
       sum(MOrderQty) as OrderQty,
       sum(MShipQty) as ShipQty,
       MStockCode
FROM SorDetail
WHERE  MOrderQty > 0
GROUP By SalesOrder,MStockCode
```

I Have joined the first two, as i want the date fields from SorMaster to be added to ArTrnDetail table using the below table : however, i am not sure how to add the aggregated table to the rest afterwards.  Please see my attempt below:

```
SELECT 
    ArTrnDetail.SalesOrder
    TrnYear,
    TrnMonth,
    InvoiceDate,
    StockCode,
    QtyInvoiced,
    SorMaster.OrderDate,
    SorMaster.ReqShipDate
FROM ArTrnDetail 

INNER JOIN 
    SorMaster ON ArTrnDetail.SalesOrder = SorMaster.SalesOrder
```

What i need now is to join the aggr table to the resulting top table, but join on SalesOrder AND StockCode.

Please can someone assist.  Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0):

You can put both queries inside CTEs and join the results

```
;WITH CTE1 AS (
    SELECT 
        ArTrnDetail.SalesOrder
        TrnYear,
        TrnMonth,
        InvoiceDate,
        StockCode,
        QtyInvoiced,
        SorMaster.OrderDate,
        SorMaster.ReqShipDate
    FROM ArTrnDetail 
    INNER JOIN SorMaster 
        ON ArTrnDetail.SalesOrder = SorMaster.SalesOrder)
,CTE2 AS (
    SELECT SalesOrder,
       sum(MOrderQty) as OrderQty,
       sum(MShipQty) as ShipQty,
       MStockCode
    FROM SorDetail
    WHERE  MOrderQty > 0
    GROUP By SalesOrder,MStockCode
)
SELECT <columns>
FROM CTE1
INNER JOIN CTE2
    ON <your join condition>
```